# Is it possible for two foreign keys to reference each other in a SQLite database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Can two foreign keys reference each other?

I have a SQLite database with a table of NBA regular season stats with a foreign key on player id referencing a Players table that has a primary key of player id. I want to create a post season stats table with another foreign key of player id, so would it make sense to have a foreign key on id in regular season stats reference player id as a foreign key in post season stats?

I attempted to set the foreign keys but it was creating an error that the key must be unique. Additionally, I'm not sure if this logically makes sense.

Comment: why would the FKs not both reference the ID from the Players table?

Comment: A foreign key from A to B requires that there is a record in B that has an primary id that matches the foreign key from A. How could you ever create a record in A, if the matching record has to be in B, when you can only create that record if B if the matching record has to be in A already? In theory, you could add both records at once - but that tells you the real solution: why not put all the columns in one table, and create a single record? However, it sounds like you really just need both B and C to reference A (players) and that's possible (and common)

Comment: No, you want to use Players id in any table that wants to associate a player with a table row. You seem to be wanting to take an extra step: post season stats to season stats to players table. But that foreign key in regular season stats isn't unique - lots of rows could reference a single player.

Answer (score 0):

No, a foreign key cannot directly reference another foreign key in a different table. Foreign keys are used to establish relationships between tables based on the values of their primary keys or unique columns. I still not getting the idea why you want to do that but if you want to make relation between post season , regular season,and player you could make two foreign keys in post season one for player and one for regular.

Answer (score -1):

In SQLite, foreign keys are used to establish relationships between tables. They enforce referential integrity, ensuring that the data in related tables remains consistent. When a foreign key is defined in a table, it creates a link to the primary key of another table.

##How many foreign keys can I have in the project and how many per tables?

In SQLite, there are no hard limits on the number of foreign keys you can have in a project or per table. The number of foreign keys you can define depends on the constraints of your database design and the capabilities of your system.